# Checkout - can't go to Payment step

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, knockout

Getting `ko_unique_1=flatrate_flatrate#shipping` in URL as param when clicking **Next** button on Shipping step. The page gets redirected to shipping step and customers are unable to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with third party integration Segmetrics. Disabling it, fixes the issue.